# JDBC Connectivity for Data Source in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We are trying to bring oracle table catalogs into glue . But unable to read the data from source

We have tried to give all the possibilities in include path parameter but unable to bring the data

Anyone tried oracle as JDBC data store for AWS Glue ? Please help us to fix the issue

Comment: Did you create a Glue Connection to the JDBC source? Please include more detail to explain what exactly have you tried.

Comment: Yes , I have created Glue connection with Oracle JDBC Source . Am trying to fetch HR schema into glue catalog . But HR schema tables not updating into glue catalog . Also in Crawlers include path value given as orcl/%